# Функции. Массив аргументов

Tags: javascript

Имеется массив аргументов arr(количество элементов неизвестно), все элементы массива надо передать функции f в качестве аргументов. Каким образом это сделать?

Comment: Открою секрет, можно вообще не передавать. Есть такое понятие как глобальная переменная.
    
    var userName = 'Вася';
    
    function showMessage() {
      var message = 'Привет, я ' + userName;
      alert(message);
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через `.apply()` [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) 
 или через [спред оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```
var  arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];

function f() { console.log(arguments) }

f.apply(null, arr);
f(...arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это, похоже, решение

Comment: @Zondic можно еще из `es2015` через спред оператор `f(...arr)`

Answer (score 2):

Передайте массив одним аргументом

```js
function func(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    console.log(i + ': ' + data[i]);
}

var test = [6, 5, 4, 'KK'];
func(test);
```

Comment: В функции не предусмотрена обработка массива аргументов, функция принимает только отдельные аргументы